# How to perform filter in java script objects?

Tags: javascript, object

How to filter javascript objects based on a condition?

I tried this , but still it fills the remaining index of the object as null , I don't want the part of object if it doesn't meet my condition ,here the condition is only if the index of the object is less the selectedIndex (which is some value in my program) it should be selected, remaining are not required

```
console.log(Object.keys(registrationData).map((val,ind)=>{
            return (ind<=selectedIndex ) ? registrationData[val] :null
   }));
```

Comment: Then use `.filter()` or `.reduce()` and not `.map()`

Comment: What is `registrationData` here? Add some sample data for it and the expected output also.

Comment: registrationData is nested object

Comment: @Andreas can you please help me with the syntax

Comment: [Indexed collections - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Object
  .values(registrationData)
  .filter((value, index) => index <= selectedIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you @v.kostenko